# Auto format Indian currency number

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, currency, autoformat

I am using following code to display currency in Indian numbering system:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function format(obj) {
      var formatted = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      obj.value = formatted.replace(/(\d+)(\d{2})/g,'$1.$2');
   }
</script>

<input type="number" onkeyup="format(this)">
```

Output I'm getting: `123456.78`

Output I want is: `1,23,45,678.00`

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

```js
const number = 12345678;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(number));
```

If that should be a currency, you can pass that as a second argument

```js
const number = 12345678;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {style: 'currency', currency: 'INR'}).format(number));
```

Or to force the two decimals:

```js
const number = 12345678;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}).format(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) will be of great help here.

```js
function convertToIndianCurrency(x){
  return x.toLocaleString('en-IN');
}

console.log(convertToIndianCurrency(123456.789));
```